# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Estoy haciendo uso de `Entity Framework` donde en mi base de datos creo mis funciones, procedimientos almacenados , vistas etc, el problema resulta ser que al momento de actualizar mi modelo de base de datos específicamente el que se ve en la imagen , accedo a la clase que se creo y resulta que al momento de actualizar el modelo lo hizo de la sgte manera,el método en donde cae el error es al momento de realizar una búsqueda que adjunto a continuacion.

```
 private void TxtBusqueda_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtBusqueda.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                dataGridPro.DataSource = daoProf.Cargar_Odontologo();
            }
            else if (txtBusqueda.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                dataGridPro.DataSource = daoProf.Buscar_Odontologo(txtBusqueda.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Posteriormente el método que realiza la búsqueda es el siguiente

```
public List<Buscar_Profesional_Odontologo_Result> Buscar_Odontologo(string NOMPRO)
        {
            DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES();
            var find_odo = db.Buscar_Profesional_Odontologo(NOMPRO);
            return find_odo.ToList();
        }
```

Esta linea de código `DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES();` contiene todos las funciones, procedimiento . vistas y tablas que tengo en la base de datos con nombre `DIENTES_SANOS` en otras palabras es el modelo `Dientes_Sanos_Model.edmx` contiene todo esto, el motivo de la pregunta es básicamente que al momento de hacer la generación del modelo ese sp una columna no le había puesto nombre a esa columna, lo actualice en la bd de sql y actualice el modelo, cuando ejecute la aplicación me lanzo el error debido a que el archivo que genero ef como se ve mas abajo una de esas columnas tiene un nombre que no corresponde.

Este es el archivo que me genere el modelo de ef

```
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Este código se generó a partir de una plantilla.
//
//     Los cambios manuales en este archivo pueden causar un comportamiento inesperado de la aplicación.
//     Los cambios manuales en este archivo se sobrescribirán si se regenera el código.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DientesSanos
{
    using System;
    
    public partial class Buscar_Profesional_Odontologo_Result
    {
        public int ODONT_ID { get; set; }
        public string ODONT_CODIGO { get; set; }
        public string ODONT_NOMBRE { get; set; }
        public string ODONT_APELLIDO { get; set; }
        public string ODONT_ESPECIALIDAD { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime C________________________________________ { get; set; } <-- ESTA COLUMNA DEBERIA SER `[ODONT_FEC_NAC]`
        public string ODONT_ID_TITULO { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Cosa que al revisar el procedimiento almacenado en la base de datos sql esta de la siguiente manera.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE[dbo].[Buscar_Profesional_Odontologo]
         @NOMPRO VARCHAR(100)
AS
SELECT [ODONT_ID],[ODONT_CODIGO],[ODONT_NOMBRE],[ODONT_APELLIDO],[ODONT_ESPECIALIDAD],[ODONT_FEC_NAC],[ODONT_ID_TITULO] 
FROM TBL_ODONTOLOGO 
where ODONT_APELLIDO like '%'+@NOMPRO+'%' AND ODONT_ESTADO!='F' 
order by ODONT_CODIGO
```

Como podría corregir o forzar que en el modelo del ef se actualice de la manera correcta?, lo he realizado desde actualizar modelo de la base de datos sin embargo sigue igual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 especialmente punto 2 y 4. Saludos.

Comment: que tal @fredyfx modifique la pregunta para tener un poco mas claro el panorama.

Comment: Aunque ya tienes más datos, todavía falta ampliar un poco más el panorama, te ayudo con las siguientes preguntas: ¿Qué hay en `DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES()` ? ¿Cómo es la tabla? ¿Cómo es la clase que se relaciona con dicha tabla? ¿Cómo estás configurando el EF?

Comment: @fredyfx creo que ahora si tienes un poco mas de detalle para que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: @fredyfx después de varios intentos, la única solución viable fue volver a agregar el  `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`  porque bajo ninguna manera se pudo actualizar el modelo :( , no se si es un bug de vs, pero me quedo de experiencia antes de actualizar el modelo verificar los procedimientos o funciones que estén correctamente, igual gracias por tu apoyo un abrazo campeón!